# NoSuchElementException on Scanner.nextLine()

Tags: java, file

I don't know why I keep getting this exception because I only have my scanner process the lines when it hasNext(). It will print the lines but then throw this exception. Here is my code:

```
PagesCollection tester = new PagesCollection();

String fileName = (args.length >  0)? args[0] : "none";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fileName), "UTF-8");

while (scan.hasNext()) {
  String line = scan.nextLine();
  line = line.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
  System.out.println(line);
  Page newPage = new Page(line);
  tester.addPage(newPage);
}
```

Exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516) 
at Webpage.countLines(Page.java:38) at Webpage.compareTo(Page.java:60) 
at Webpage.compareTo(Page.java:14) 
at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1144) 
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1079) 
at PagesCollection.addPage(PagesCollection.java:32) 
at PagesCollection.main(PagesCollection.java:75)
```

Comment: Can you provide the Exception stack

Comment: Where the Exception occurs, the input still has next tokens on current line, but has no next line .

Comment: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516)
 at Webpage.countLines(Page.java:38)
 at Webpage.compareTo(Page.java:60)
 at Webpage.compareTo(Page.java:14)
 at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1144)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1079)
 at PagesCollection.addPage(PagesCollection.java:32)
 at PagesCollection.main(PagesCollection.java:75)

Comment: Do you get the same error if you change `scan.nextLine` to `scan.next`?

Comment: Answer is in your stacktrace.

Comment: Yes I get the same error

Comment: Put the contents of your file if possible... that'll make things much easier to debug...

Comment: https://www.facebook.com
http://www.netflix.com

Comment: those are the file contents

Comment: No it reads the URLs. I know that it's doing that because it prints out both of them before it throws this exception! That's what is so puzzling

Comment: The URLs are strings

Answer (score 2):

Since you get the same error when changing `scan.nextLine` to `scan.next`, looks like you might've stumbled across this bug[1].

- [1] http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8139414

Answer (score 0):

It could be text in the file without "\n" character. So, hasNext() is true but nextLine() doesn't exist.

Better use check hasNextLine() to be sure about next line.

Comment: I thought that too but I get the same error with hasNextLine()